# Volume label on 2TB Seagate Backup Plus Slim external hard drive does not appear in Windows Explorer (but is visible in Disk Management)

Tags: windows, backup, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

I've been experiencing some weird things with my Seagate drives. I think this happened when I tried to "vaccinate" the drives with Panda Free Anti-Virus. My WD 2TB and my internal hard drives worked fine so I'm confused.

[image: Disk Manager Screenshot]

As you guys can see, my label name is not reflected under Windows Explorer. Tried loads of methods like renaming in registry, cmd and all didn't do a thing. It is certainly not an autorun.inf issue as well since I tried to put in another name but seems like the drive disregards that and the Seagate.ico.

If it were just a naming issue that will be fine but since then, whenever I transfer new files (mainly videos) to the drive, the new transfers might disappear, leaving me in pain. It honestly sucks since I bought two of these, using up to 1.5 TB on both of them since I read favourable reviews on Amazon regarding the 2 TB drives.

I tried to find out about my problems in this forum and elsewhere but couldn't seem to get the right info relating to my problem. I tried plugging it into another computer of mine and a friend's laptop, all running Windows (from 7 to 8.1 and 10) and still got the same problem.

I just tried to do a quick format and a full format. Neither worked.

Comment: The partition table may be corrupt—try using `diskpart clean` to wipe the partition table, then repartition and reformat the hard drive and see if it helps.

Comment: be aware that what @bwDraco has suggested will clear all data off of the HDD - back it all up first if you're going to do that.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your feedback. Though I did say the full format did not work, it appears that the naming is surprisingly reflected in Windows Explorer after the full reformat though it did not take place instantly. Just finished transferring all my files back and after plugging it into my 2 PCs repeatedly, nothing gets corrupted. My only nitpick is that the autorun.inf does not work for me so I can't see the Seagate.ico file as the disk drive image.

@bwDraco I will try to use diskpart clean for my second drive just to be safe.

Comment: Did you try to rename the volume in explorer?

Comment: @Moab Yup, it can now work like a normal drive. Apparently quick format worked on my second drive as Windows Explorer showed the actual label name after I plugged it back once the quick format was done. Guess I raised this issue for naught but I wonder what really happened to make the drives like that.